# Will the Ubuntu One Music Store be available for Banshee in 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu-one, banshee

I heared that Rhythmbox will replace Banshee as the default music player in Precise. However, I was still surprised not to find the Ubuntu One Music Store plugin for Banshee in Precise. It has been available from Lucid, where Rhythmbox was also the default music player, so I would not have expected it to be discontinued as a result of that switch.

So will the U1 Music Store be available in the final version of Precise, or is it dropped completely?

Comment: It's only a matter of time I would say. Canonical wouldn't drop support for that plugin as people pay to sync their purchased music through ubuntu one music.

Answer (score 8):

Because Banshee is still using GTK+ 2.x, and because Rhythmbox and Ubuntu, are pushing forward to GTK+ 3.x, we can no longer support both with the same code and build. Therefore, Banshee will not have the U1 Music Store in 12.04.

There is some work to move Banshee over to GTK+ 3.x upstream, but it is not landed in the master repository, and is blocking on some issues with a gtk-sharp 3.x release. When that is widely available, it should be pretty easy for us to ship an extension for Banshee again as well.

I'll also be moving the code for the extension, out of the Banshee tree, and into its own project soon, so that it can be fixed and released, without being tied directly to the upstream Banshee releases.

Comment: I have used the U1 music store in banshee to buy music all the time and now you are telling me it is not available anymore? You guys should have come up with a solution beforehand. That is quite frustrating after upgrading.